# Copy, mirror or synchronize a directory structure -- but only the file names, without content

Tags: windows, sync

Say I have a huge directory structure of movie files.

For analysis of that structure, I want to copy or synchronize the entire directory structure, i.e. folders and files.

However, I don't want to copy the movie files, while I want to keep their file names.

Ideally, I get zero-byte files with the original movie file name in the mirrored directory structure.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: You can easily copy the folder structure without content, but not filenames with no content so far as I know.   ......   https://camerondwyer.com/2013/07/05/how-to-copy-an-entire-folder-structure-without-copying-the-files-tip-for-starting-the-new-financial-year/

Comment: First thing I thought of was NeoFinder, but it's Mac-only. I discovered it does have a 'sister' app using the same database structure - [abeMedia](http://www.cdwinder.de). It's basically just a cataloguing app. I've used the Mac one for decades to catalogue CD & DVD data safeties. Basically, it's what you asked for, all the structure, none of the content. It just doesn't do it *quite* how you asked.

Comment: Judging by [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1441275/432690) it's `Robocopy /CREATE`. I have no experience with it, therefore just a comment.

Comment: [Official Microsoft Documentation for Robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy).